# What is the best way to automatically delete table rows (free plan)?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

I am using the free plan for a personal project, so can't afford to move to a better (paid) one. Unfortunately, my database filled and stupid me did a reset, thinking it will delete only the rows, leaving the structure intact. But it deleted everything, so now I have to rebuild it.
Before I start, I'd like to know if there is a way to empty old records/rows from the database. If I could manage to do this automatically (ideally there are some heroku settings that can do this, something I've missed), so I won't reach the 10000 monthly limit, it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

There are no safeguards built into the platform to delete rows on your behalf. You will need to do it manually or teach one of your applications to do it programmatically.